# Where is my Touchpad toggle button missing (Windows 11)?

Tags: mouse, windows-11, touchpad

I'm using a Windows 11 machine and I'm trying to disable the touchpad when an external mouse is plugged in. But, when I go into the settings for the Touchpad:

```
Settings > Bluetooth & devices > Touchpad
```

...this is what I see:

[image: Image of Touchpad settings on Windows 11 machine]

I've run updates and I'm not missing anything. The Touchpad is an Elan Touchpad and it's driver is updated. I've restarted the computer after updates made, but nothing.

Any idea how to bring back the toggle button or any of the additional settings?

Comment: Go to device manager, uninstall the touchpad and then click on scan for hardware changes, restart you pc, see if it's back then?

Comment: Do you know that your system had this function to begin with?